# Generating Pythagorean Triples From One Leg

Tags: triangles, pythagorean-triples

The question is simple: Find the longest possible hypotenuse in a right triangle with integer sides where the shortest side has length T. What I am asking is if there are any means to approach this besides testing pythagorean triples by brute force.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If the given side is $T$, there will exist an $n$ such that $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1>T^2$.

Answer (score 1):

For any given length, A,B, or C, there will be
$\,2^{x-1}\,$ Pythagorean triples with that side length where $\,x\,$ is the number of distinct prime factors of that length. The alternatives for longeest hypotenuse depend on whether that side length is odd or even.
We use Euclid's formula
$\, A=m^2-n^2\quad B=2mn \quad C=m^2+n^2$

For $\,A\,(odd),\,$ the longest hypotenuse will be for a triple where $\,C-B=1\,$ and
$\, m=\dfrac{A+1}{2},\, n=\dfrac{A-1}{2},\, e.g.
A=5\implies (m,k)=(3,2),\, C=13.$

For $\,B\,$ (any multiple of $\,4\,$), the longest hypotenuse will be for a triple where $\,C-A=2\,$ and
$\, m=\dfrac{B}{2},\, n=1\, e.g.
B=12\implies (m,k)=(6,1),\,C=37.$